# Representing timetable to be database-friendly

Tags: sql, excel, database

How do I convert a roster which was formatted as below

| Name | Aug-01 | Aug-02 | Aug-03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Kitchen | Prep | Off |
| Paul | Prep | Off | Serving |
| Sarah | Serving | Kitchen | Prep |
| Lily | Off | Serving | Kitchen |

To a database-friendly form like

| Name | Date | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Aug-01 | Kitchen |
| Paul | Aug-01 | Prep |
| Sarah | Aug-01 | Serving |
| Lily | Aug-01 | Off |
| Bob | Aug-02 | Prep |
| Paul | Aug-02 | Off |
| Sarah | Aug-02 | Kitchen |
| Lily | Aug-02 | Serving |
| Bob | Aug-03 | Off |
| Paul | Aug-03 | Serving |
| Sarah | Aug-03 | Prep |
| Lily | Aug-03 | Kitchen |

I did try to search for previous answers but I couldn't figure out the right search key.

Comment: Search this forum for `unpivot`. There are plenty of examples and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select name, 'Aug-01' as date, [Aug-01] as position
from t
union all
select name, 'Aug-02' as date, [Aug-02] as position
from t
select name, 'Aug-03' as date, [Aug-03] as position
from t;
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks